# updating interface in GTK

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I want to make an application that displays the time (ultimately I am trying to hack together my own simple smart mirror without using the existing smart mirror APIs). I am using GTK3 for the UI however I am having trouble figuring out a solution to make the UI update the time (I am not experienced in front end or GTK so bear with me).

I have tried placing loops around parts of the view3 code shown below however I have discovered that once gtk_main() is called I can't get out of the gtk main loop so that the while loop starts over and recalls the time function I wrote.

I have tried using functions like gtk_main_iteration_do(gtk_false()) (false so that it doesn't block) but I clearly don't understand enough about these functions because it's not working. If I leave gtk_main() out of the loop obviously gtk_main() never gets called and my application window won't even open up.

I have shown the relevant code in main below and following that the definition of the get_time_string() function I wrote.

```
int
main (int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
  // initialization and setting up window, packing widgets, etc

  // view3
  // populate buffer with time string
  // and insert into text view
  view3 = gtk_text_view_new();
  gtk_widget_set_name(view3, "view3");
  buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view3));
  gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(buffer, &iter, 0);
  gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, get_time_string(), -1);
  gtk_text_view_set_editable(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view3), FALSE);
  gtk_text_view_set_cursor_visible(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view3), FALSE);


  // More widget packing, setting up UI

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Definition of get_time_string()

```
char* get_time_string(){
  time_t time_var = time(NULL);
  struct tm *info;
  char *time_string = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
  info = localtime( &time_var );
  strftime(time_string, 100, "%I:%M %p", info);
  return time_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not play with mainloop iterations unless you really need or know what to do.

The trick is to use g_timeout_add or g_idle_add and their variants. As you want the time to update at regular intervals (for minute resolution you will update every 60 seconds) then you can use g_timeout_add_seconds.

For illustration purposes, i'll add the seconds to your time string and update every second, using your get_time_string function but creating a very simple window to show just a time label:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

char* get_time_string(){
  time_t time_var = time(NULL);
  struct tm *info;
  char *time_string = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
  info = localtime( &time_var );
  strftime(time_string, 100, "%I:%M:%S %p", info);
  return time_string;
}

gboolean update_label_time (gpointer user_data) {
   gchar *t = get_time_string();
   gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(user_data), t);
   g_free (t);
   return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   gchar *t;
   GtkWidget *window;
   GtkWidget *label_time; 

   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
   t = get_time_string();
   label_time = gtk_label_new (t);
   g_free (t);

   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
   gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), label_time);


   g_timeout_add_seconds(0.5, update_label_time, label_time);


   gtk_widget_show_all(window);

   gtk_main();

   return 0;
}
```

The result should be a window with a label updating every second:

[image]

GLib has its own [time functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html) which you should use.

Comment: Hey José, you're leaking the memory of the string allocated in `get_time_string`. Another problem is that `g_timeout_add_seconds` is not really accurate and documentation says `Note that the first call of the timer may not be precise for timeouts of one second`. So `g_timeout_add` with a 500ms sampling should avoid having the same time displayed fo 2 seconds for example.

Comment: @libforce you're correct, my bad. Thanks for the feedback. All the best!

Comment: De nada, tenha um bom dia ;)

Comment: @liberforce :D congrats on ur portuguese :D Tudo de bom.